# Looking for raw RGB video data files OR tips to create same from

Tags: file, video, rgb

I want to apply sobel filter algorithm on RGB video data frames and my problem is that I am unable to get RGB vide data files from the internet OR dont know how to create same on my PC.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Regards,
Suman

Answer (score 0):

Get some video file and use ffmpeg to export certain number of frames as raw bitmaps.